grpc client retryPolicy breaks when server uses gRPC+HTTP/2 h2c mux
In production I have a grpc server that also uses grpc-gateway to expose the http API. We have been using an approach similar to this to mux the grpc server and the grpc-gateway over the same tcp port. This has been working fine, until later when I added a "retryPolicy" to all of our grpc clients, and then noticed that the retryPolicy is entirely ignored in all clients.
I've managed to reduce the production code into a simpler standalone example that illustrates the problem.

client.go: https://gist.github.com/justinfx/d3d5b6aab2ccf8fc7a4d7fa4c10bfa59#file-client-go
server.go: https://gist.github.com/justinfx/d3d5b6aab2ccf8fc7a4d7fa4c10bfa59#file-server-go

The server is set up to fail the first 3 attempts and succeed on the 4th. When you run the client, you will see that it actually fails immediately on the first attempt, ignoring the retryPolicy. This behaviour is the same regardless of the client, as I have the same client also failing under Python.
After experimenting I have found that the cmux package is actually able to make this work as expected:

server_cmux.go: https://gist.github.com/justinfx/d3d5b6aab2ccf8fc7a4d7fa4c10bfa59#file-server_cmux-go

However, as per the article explaining my original approach, there are caveats to using cmux.
I'm wondering what I am doing wrong in the h2c approach that would cause it not to be able to do the grpc retryPolicy operations.
